# How to escape leading square bracket in a parameter array in Bicep?

Tags: azure, azure-bicep

I'm getting "Deployment template language expression evaluation failed" error from bicep template validation due to leading square bracket. If I add another square bracket it passes but the extra bracket will be appended.
Example:

```
var test='[xxxxxx]'
var arr=[
{
 name: 'varname'
  value: test
}
]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As discussed [issue](https://github.com/Azure/bicep/issues/5788) here in github,

Bicep is working appropriately here by producing a single `[`-> ARM expressions should only be escaped with `[[`if the string's initial letter is a `[`. Because the use of multi-line strings in Bicep results in extra spaces at the beginning of the string, the `[`should not be escaped.

***Fix this by giving*** `' []'` ***instead of*** `'[]'`

*I tried below sample variable file with a "**single variable**" declared in bicep and successfully deployed after build got succeeded*.

***var.bicep:***

```bash
var test = ' []'
module mod './<stringfile>.bicep' = { //Added parameters in another bicep file.
  name: 'module'
  params: {
    test: test
  }
}
```

***modulefile.bicep***:

```bash
param test string
```

***Deployment succeeded:***

[image]

***Deployed in the Portal:***

[image]

***AND***

2. [As mentioned in some examples from MsDoc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/bicep/bicep-functions-array#examples), *I've taken a snippet and ran in my environment with multiple* "***variable arrays***", *and it was successfully deployed as shown*:

```bash
var  names = [
'xxx'
'yyy'
'zzz'
]
var digits = [
4
2
7
]
output  index  int = lastIndexOf(names, 'yyy')
output  indexs  int = indexOf(digits, '4')
output  notFoundIndex  int = lastIndexOf(names, 'zzz')
```

***Deployment succeeded:***

[image]

***Deployed in the Portal:***

[image]

Comment: Yes, adding empty string to the beginning of the value did the trick. Thanks a lot!